# Handler Looper and MessageQueue

Tags: android

It is correct that the Handler sends a message to the MessageQueue by using the Looper, but gets/takes a message from MessageQueue directly without using the Looper?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java

Answer (score 0):

Handler's `sendMessage` just does enqueue to the `MessageQueue` (no Looper involved). `Looper` itself - is just an indefinite loop which monitors `MessageQueue` and does `dequeue` whenever new message arrived

Comment: you mean dequeue to Handler? and what with enqueue, loop does it?

Comment: Handler does enqueue. Looper does dequeue